# View below a layout not clickable after upper layout set View.GONE

Tags: android, layout, view

The imageView **start_messaging** is not clickable after the **searchList** visibility is made **GONE** from **VISIBLE** even though only the first item in recyclerView is clickable in that fragment but not this button. However the button is clickable before the **searchList** was visible. You may preview the video for better clarification.

Video: https://youtube.com/shorts/MT9cMwZ5qdg?si=T7ERP5oFaojZDA-I

**activity_dashboard.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/app_background_color"
    tools:context=".activities.DashboardActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/topBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNav">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_3sdp">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_constraint"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/currentTab"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/alata"
                    android:text="@string/recent_chats"
                    android:textColor="@color/app_font_theme_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_16ssp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/searchUsers"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/search" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/searchBar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar_constraint">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                    android:id="@+id/search_input_field"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/search_view_background"
                    app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                    app:queryHint="Username or phone num" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/callStatusHome"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/searchBar_layout"
                android:background="@color/app_component_color"
                android:fontFamily="@font/alata">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Call Ongoing"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_11ssp"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/alata"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/searchList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@color/red"
                tools:listitem="@layout/chat_face"
                android:elevation="@dimen/_10sdp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/callStatusHome"/>


            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/callStatusHome"/>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_circular"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:indeterminateTint="@color/app_component_color"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <com.etebarian.meowbottomnavigation.MeowBottomNavigation
        android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:mbn_circleColor="#ffffff"
        app:mbn_backgroundBottomColor="@color/white"
        app:mbn_countBackgroundColor="#ff6f00"
        app:mbn_countTextColor="#ffffff"
        app:mbn_defaultIconColor="#90a4ae"
        app:mbn_rippleColor="#2f424242"
        app:mbn_selectedIconColor="#075864"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:mbn_shadowColor="#1f212121"/>


<!--    <Button-->
<!--        android:id="@+id/signOut"-->
<!--        android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
<!--        android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
<!--        android:text="Sign Out"-->
<!--        android:textAllCaps="false"-->
<!--        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"-->
<!--        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"-->
<!--        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"-->
<!--        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"-->
<!--        />-->

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**fragment_chat.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/c1"
    android:background="@color/app_background_color"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".fragments.ChatFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/c2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_3sdp">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_circular"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:indeterminateTint="@color/app_component_color"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/recentChatsRecycler"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recentChatsRecycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:stackFromEnd="true"
            app:reverseLayout="true"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            tools:itemCount="15"
            tools:listitem="@layout/chat_face"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/start_messaging"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/start_messaging_icon"
            android:elevation="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_15sdp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/recentChatsRecycler"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/recentChatsRecycler" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**CODE**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityDashboardBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        binding.searchUsers.setOnClickListener {
            if (!checkSearchCLickState){
                checkSearchCLickState = true
                Log.d("special1", "onCreate: Clicked")
                fetchAllUsers()
                showSearchPanel()
            }else{
                checkSearchCLickState = false
                hideSearchPanel()
            }
        }
}

    private fun showSearchPanel(){
        val scaleAnim = ScaleAnimation(
            1f, 1f,
            0f, 1f,
            Animation.ABSOLUTE, 1f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f
        )
        scaleAnim.duration = 200
        scaleAnim.repeatCount = 0
        scaleAnim.interpolator = AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()
        scaleAnim.fillAfter = true
        scaleAnim.fillBefore = true
        scaleAnim.isFillEnabled = true
        scaleAnim.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
            override fun onAnimationStart(p0: Animation?) {
                binding.searchList.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.searchBarLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                //binding.frame.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.frame.fadeVisibility(View.GONE, 300)
            }

            override fun onAnimationEnd(p0: Animation?) {

            }
            override fun onAnimationRepeat(p0: Animation?) {

            }
        })
        binding.searchBarLayout.startAnimation(scaleAnim)
        binding.searchList.startAnimation(scaleAnim)
        binding.searchUsers.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.close_icon))
    }

    private fun hideSearchPanel(){
        val scaleAnim = ScaleAnimation(
            1f, 1f,
            1f, 0f,
            Animation.ABSOLUTE, 1f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f
        )
        scaleAnim.duration = 200
        scaleAnim.repeatCount = 0
        scaleAnim.interpolator = AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()
        scaleAnim.fillAfter = true
        scaleAnim.fillBefore = true
        scaleAnim.isFillEnabled = true

        scaleAnim.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
            override fun onAnimationStart(p0: Animation?) {

            }

            override fun onAnimationEnd(p0: Animation?) {
                binding.searchList.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.searchBarLayout.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.frame.fadeVisibility(View.VISIBLE, 300)
            }
            override fun onAnimationRepeat(p0: Animation?) {

            }
        })

        binding.searchBarLayout.startAnimation(scaleAnim)
        binding.searchList.startAnimation(scaleAnim)
        binding.searchUsers.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.search))
    }

   fun View.fadeVisibility(visibility: Int, duration: Long = 400) {
        val transition: Transition = Fade()
        transition.duration = duration
        transition.addTarget(this)
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(this.parent as ViewGroup, transition)
        this.visibility = visibility
    }
```

I am trying to figure out why it's not clickable as there is nothing above that imageView. I am expecting a clear explanation of this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android:elevation="@dimen/_10sdp"
```

This line was causing the problem, I just removed the elevation from the **searchList** and now no touch problem.